# Change Keybinding for window previews

Tags: shortcut-keys

Something (a compiz plugin ?) shows a preview of all the windows when I hit Shift+Alt+Up.
like this:

[image]

I can't find the key binding in CCSM , what provides this feature, and where can I change the key binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this in the Scale plugin:

[image]